# Which one is right: "Some of the advantages of/to this technology"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which one is right,  "Some of the advantages of this technology" or "Some of the advantages to this technology"?

Comment: The first one is on the left, the second one on the right.  Except for the final word, that is.  As to which is more proper, that would depend on the context, wouldn't it?

Comment: It would raise your chance to get useful answers if you used a more specific headline that disclosed your actual topic. You could include your key word "advantages" in the headline.

Answer (score 2):

The correct phrase would be the one with "of" - assuming it's the beginning of a sentence. Look at it this way: you are talking about the technology's advantages in a possessive sense, so they are the advantages of that technology.
You could use the word "to" in some contexts, usually with the singular, e.g. "It is an advantage to learn to drive", although that still doesn't sound especially pleasant.